# Does anyone have a patchset to get FastBT running on windows?

Tags: anti-virus

Short explanation:  I am doing some anti-virus research.  [FastBT](http://nebelwelt.net/projects/fastbt/) is very intriguing.  It is a tool for doing something like binary instrumentation with a specific purpose of adding an additional layer of security at run-time.  It works great on Linux based OS-es.  I'm looking for a windows patch-set or a similar tool/implementation for windows without having to right a pin-tool from scratch or delve deeply in to DynamoRIO.

There are no active tags for binary-instrumentation or dynamic-binary-instrumentation.